# Can't find what the third argument is for in angularjs hotkeys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hotkeys

I'm trying to use angularjs hotkeys in my application and I've ran across the part where I can bind the hotkeys in my angular routes. The example given by the creator was the following:

```
 angular.module('myApp').config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/', {
   controller: 'RestaurantsController',
   templateUrl: 'views/restaurants.html',
   hotkeys: [
     ['p', 'Sort by price', 'index.html']
   ]
   });
 });
```

Found here : https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys

When I try changing the hotkeys, I get an error on the third argument:

Error: $parse:syntax

which is a syntax error. I know it's probably a syntax error, but I have no clue what the third argument is trying to accept.

What I'm simply trying to do is when the 'p' button is pressed, it will go to the index.html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third option appears to be a function in the example given on the page you linked to:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'RestaurantsController',
    templateUrl: 'views/restaurants.html',
    hotkeys: [
      ['p', 'Sort by price', 'sort(price)']
    ]
  });
});
```

I suggest you provide a function on your controller that'll load the index page.

Comment: I figured haha. I created the function inside the given controller and it ran perfectly fine..Now I'm trying to figure out how to shorten the hotkeys line because I have many routes..Any insight?